# How to chunk up an interval in Python?

Tags: python, xrange

Is there a built-in/existing library function that is like `xrange` but splits an interval into even spaced non-overlapping chunks?

For instance, if we call this function `xchunks`, then I would like:

```
>>> xchunks(start=0, stop=18, step=5)
[(0, 4), (5, 9), (10, 14), (15, 17)]
```

Ideally, this should also work for negative `step`.

```
>>> xchunks(start=20, stop=2, step=5)
[(20, 16), (15, 11), (10, 6), (5, 3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

the full solution to this would look like:

```
[(s, (s+step-1 if s+step-1<stop-1 else stop-1)) for s in xrange(start,stop,step)]
```

use range or xrange, whichever you like.

Answer (score 0):

This (almost) does what you want:

```
[(s, s + step - 1) for s in range(start, stop, step)]
```

Result:

```
[(0, 4), (5, 9), (10, 14), (15, 19)]
```

You can improve on this an make the last pair `(15, 17)`.

Answer (score 0):

This gives an iterator as with `xrange` and also works with a negative `step`. If you're using Python 3.x then replace `xrange` with `range`.

```
def xchunks(start, stop, step):
    return ((i, min(i + step - 1, stop - 1)) if step > 0 else
            (i, max(i + step + 1, stop + 1))
            for i in xrange(start, stop, step))


def test():
    result = list(xchunks(start=0, stop=18, step=5))
    print list(result)
    assert result == [(0, 4), (5, 9), (10, 14), (15, 17)]

    result = list(xchunks(start=20, stop=2, step=-5))
    print list(result)
    assert result == [(20, 16), (15, 11), (10, 6), (5, 3)]
```